# (PHP)Unit testing with dependency injection (DI)

Tags: php, dependency-injection, phpunit

Over the past few days i read a lot about Dependency Injection. 
Now since I am trying to upgrade my phpunit skills i was thinking how to implement this DI. in my unit tests.

Say I have two objects:

```
class Event{
}

class Shift{
    public function __construct(Event $e)
    {
        (...)
    }
}
```

This how i essentially understand DI.
Now I want to write a test for my shift constructor:

```
class ShiftTest extends
    \ModelTestCase
{
    public function testCanCreateShift()
    {
        $e = new \Js\Entity\Event();
        $this->assertInstanceOf('JS\Entity\Shift', new \JS\Entity\Shift($e));
    }
}
```

But now i dont want to define here a complete event object. So what is the adviced way to create my event object in phpUnit?

Comment: *(reference)* http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what mocks, stubs. etc. are used for. You create a SUT (system under test), and mock out all dependencies. 
You wouldn't be able to do this without DI in the first place.

Comment: But should i use a stub or a mock?

Comment: The biggest difference is that stubs test state (ie., after I do x, the state of y will be z), and mocks test behavior (ie., if I do x, y will happen).

This is formidable article on the subject: http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html